# How to adjust the size of dots in regplot seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using the function regplot in seaborn to plot a figure. Is there a way to adjust the size of the dots? I didn't think I can find it.
[link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html?highlight=regplot#seaborn.regplot)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `scatter_kws=` argument. You can pass a dictionary of options to be passed to `plt.scatter`

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips, scatter_kws={'s':100, 'facecolor':'red'})
```

[image]

Comment: than you a lot. that's what i'm looking for!